# How to extract last, unique and consecutive values from a data frame

Tags: r

I have extracted from a .txt  file certain strings and the corresponding lines into a data frame. How can i extract the last, unique, consecutive values from it into a new dataframe?

Here is the sample df:

````
```
Line <- c(seq(from = 1, length.out = 9, by = 421), 4211)
string <- rep(c("Plate 1", "Plate 2", " Plate 3"))
Text <- c(rep(string, length.out = 9), "Plate 3")

df <- data.frame(Line = Line,
                 Text = Text )
```
````

This is what i am trying to get:

````
```

my_df <- data.frame(Line = c(2527, 2948, 3369),
                    Text = c("Plate 1", "Plate 2", "Plate 3"))
```
````

I have tried to slice it like so:

````
```
df %>% group_by(Text) %>% slice(unique(last(n())))
```
````

But this gets the duplicate with wrong Line.

Is there a way to look at consecutive values in R, and not just remove the last Line?

Comment: `df %>%
  group_by(Text) %>%
  filter(row_number = n())`

Comment: Hi Sonny, thanks for the quick reply. This code gives me an error. When I used 
 ``` row_number() == n() ``` , the code gives me the wrong Line for Plate 3. It gives me 4211, while i need the previous one: 3369

Comment: Please update the question with the correct sample data.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, i just did :)

Comment: For `Plate 3`, why not 4211 ?

Comment: Because that is the duplicate and i need the Plate in combination with Line. I need all the Plates to have an equal distance from each other, in this case 421. So i can later use the Lines to carve out chunks from within the data. For example if i want the contents of Plate 2, subtract the Lines between Plate 3 and Plate 2, and so on for the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `n` to be the length of `string` and then use `rollapplyr` to find the indexes of the right ends of the sequences that equal `trimws(string)`.  Take the last one and use `seq` to derive the corresponding sequence from its right endpoint and then finally subscript `df` by that.

```
library(zoo)

n <- length(string)
r <- rollapplyr(as.character(df$Text), n, identical, trimws(string), fill = FALSE)
df[seq(to = tail(which(r), 1), length = n), ]
```

giving:

```
  Line    Text
7 2527 Plate 1
8 2948 Plate 2
9 3369 Plate 3
```

Comment: I like this answer very much. Follow-up: Does this work when i have more than one duplicates?

Comment: The code looks for the last occurrence of contguous elements matching `trimws(string)` regardless of what else is there so it should not matter what other junk strings are there.  Try it on some examples to satisfy yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the leading space from the strings and then use `rle` to remove duplicates

```
df$Text <- stringr::str_trim(df$Text)
df[cumsum(rle(df$Text)$lengths) > 1,] %>%
  group_by(Text) %>%
  filter(row_number() == n())
# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   Text [3]
   Line Text   
  <dbl> <chr>  
1  2527 Plate 1
2  2948 Plate 2
3  3369 Plate 3
```